# Как правильно подойти к верстке динамического шаблона?

Tags: php, html, css

Наверно все знают про студии которые занимаются продажей шаблонов под разные движки. В админке есть настройки к шаблону, например в фотогалереи можно поставить разное количество колонок в определенном блоке, причем в другом месте сайта будет другое кол-во колонок. Как сие верстается и какими инструментами пользоваться? Хочу попробовать реализовать такое у себя в самописке, естественно не полностью. До селе верстал и как-то не думал об этом-:), а вот сегодня понял что куча страниц к каждому блоку (ведь может быть несколько вариантов отображения и не все они подойдут под общий html каркас) не есть хорошо. Проблема также и с выводом из БД сего если будет куча HTML макетов. Конечно подозреваю что частично JavaScript (который я мало знаю впрочем) решит мои проблемы, но боюсь опять упереться в стену. Может у кого-то есть опыт по реализации подобного?

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, вы ищете [muuri](https://muuri.dev/), [sortable](https://sortablejs.github.io/sortablejs/), [isotope](https://isotope.metafizzy.co/) или [packery](https://packery.metafizzy.co/).
Это даст повод для размышлений.